# html - enclosing td inside div

Tags: html

I have a table and want to include a div inside it such that the div encloses some of the table rows. However it's not working.

```
<table>
<tr><td> one</td></tr>

<div style="color: yellow;">
<tr><td> two</td></tr>
<tr><td> three</td></tr>
</div>

<tr><td> four </td></tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to enclose table rows within a div?

Many thanks for any suggestion provided.

Comment: As others have mentioned, what you want to do isn't possible.  You may, however be able to simply set the two <tr>s with a style of "color: yellow" to achieve a similar effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `<tbody>` tag to group rows together:

```
<table>
    <tr><td> one</td></tr>
    <tbody style="color: yellow;">
        <tr><td> two</td></tr>
        <tr><td> three</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody style="color: red;">
        <tr><td> four </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[Test case](http://jsfiddle.net/xq7mU/).

Answer (score 4):

No, that is not possible.

The only place where you can put any content in a table is inside the cells.

Perhaps you want a header and a footer in the table? Note that the footer comes before the body:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><td> one</td></tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr><td> four </td></tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody style="color: yellow;">
    <tr><td> two</td></tr>
    <tr><td> three</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

That would be invalid HTML.. so not possible.

you could instead add a class to the rows you want and use css to style it.

```
<table>
<tr><td> one</td></tr>
<tr class="colored"><td> two</td></tr>
<tr class="colored"><td> three</td></tr>
<tr><td> four </td></tr>
</table>
```

and in css

```
.colored td{ color: yellow; }
```

---

As mentioned in other answers you can use the [`<tbody>` tag <sup>w3c docs</sup>](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-TBODY) for grouping, which allows for multiple instances in a table

```
<table>
    <tr><td> one</td></tr>
    <tbody class="colored">
        <tr><td> two</td></tr>
        <tr><td> three</td></tr>
    </tbody>
    <tr><td> four </td></tr>
    <tbody class="colored">
        <tr><td> five</td></tr>
        <tr><td> six</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/n2yWe/

Answer (score 1):

It is possible (you just did it) but strongly not recommended since according to the w3c spec you cannot nest `div` under `table`. The browsers will probably act differently since no defined behaviour is required here.

Comment: Well, you can write it in the HTML code, but the browser will not put the div element around the row elements.

Comment: probably not won't. But I saw many pieces of invalid HTML doing weird things. Who knows what will be the result in all the browsers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions, finally opted for the <tbody> tag

Comment: The only certain thing is that the div element won't end up where the tag is. Some possible results is that the div ends up before the table, after the table, inside an implicitly created cell, or ignored.